# How to animate two input fields (HTML) using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, slide

I am currently working on a website, and I have two input fields. I want them to slip to the middle from the side of the page when the page refresh (or when you arrive at the website). How can I do that? Maybe with Javascript?

Here are my two inputs:

```
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username"><br><br><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br><br><br>
  <form action="profile.html">
    <input type="submit" value="login" id="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS `keyframes` without javascript

```css
input{
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;

}
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username"><br><br><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br><br><br>
  <form action="profile.html">
    <input type="submit" value="login" id="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: the solution looks beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery animate function to update CSS properties.

**Sample code:**

```
$('#username').animate({display: 'block'}, 'fast');
```

**You can update more css properties :**

```
$('#username').animate({display: 'block', font-size: '22px'}, 'fast');
```

[Read More about JQuery animate function](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Or You can use Library called Animate CSS:

[Animate Library](https://animate.style/)

Hope this will be useful.